# Strange Behavior with Closure in Google's Dartlang

Tags: javascript, dart, closures

I would have expected the integer 'i' in this Dart program to have been set to 9 before the first function was called.  However the output for this program is...

0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ,14, 16, 18

When I would have normally expected 10, 11, 12, 13.... as it is with JavaScript, C# etc..

Dart Lang Output: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ,14, 16, 18

```
typedef int TestFun(int x);

void main()
{
    List<TestFun> functionList = new List<TestFun>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {        
        functionList.add( (int x) => x + i );      
    }

    for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
    {
        print(functionList[j](j));
    }    
}
```

Equivalent JavaScript.... Output 10,11,12...

```
var functionList = new Array;

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    functionList[i] = function (x) { return x + i } ;
}

for ( var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    alert( functionList[j](j) );
}
```

Equivalent C#.... Output 10,11,12...

```
public delegate int TestDel(int x);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<TestDel> functionList = new List<TestDel>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        functionList.Add((int x) => x + i);      
    }

    for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(functionList[j](j));
    }    
}
```

**Is this a Dart bug?  Can someone explain this behavior to me?**

Comment: There seems to be a bug `(int x) => x + 1`. I guess you want `(int x) => x + i`

Comment: yep, copy and pasted the wrong example code.  it's fixed now, thanks

Comment: perhaps you should give them a try :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dart deliberately avoids the error-prone behavior of JavaScript here.
A for loop that declares its own variable will have a new version of that variable for each iteration. This goes both for `for(var x = ...;;)` and `for (var x in ...)` (and in the latter case, the variable can even be final).

Example showing that each iteration introduces a new independent variable:

```dart
class Box {
  final Function set;
  final Function get;
  Box(this.get, this.set);
  String toString() => "[${get()}]";
}
main() {
  var boxes = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    boxes.add(new Box(()=>i, (x) { i = x; }));
  }
  print(boxes);  // [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    boxes[i].set(i * 2 + 1); 
  }
  print(boxes);  // [[1], [3], [5], [7], [9]]
}
```

Comment: It might help if you think of a for (...) loop as equivalent to [0,1,2,3,4,...].forEach((i) =>  There are differences, but it's illustrative about the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion seems weird to me.

The first closure you add is actually (i = 0)

```dart
functionList[i] = function (x) { return x + 0 } ;
```

In the second `for` loop (first iteration) you execute this first function with the argument `0`. How should this result to `10`?

**EDIT**

To avoid the behavior mentioned by lrn you can put the variable inside an object

```dart
typedef int TestFun(int x);

class Int {
  int val;
  Int(this.val);
}

void main() {
  List<TestFun> functionList = [];

  for (Int i = new Int(0); i.val < 10; i.val++) {
    functionList.add((int x) => x + i.val);
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    print(functionList[j](j));
  }
}
```

Comment: the variable i's scope is constrained to the for loop, until it is folded into the closure.  however, i keeps iterating up before the anonymous function is called.  By the time the first function in the array is called... the value of 'i' should be 9.  give it a try, the javascript example i posted was only tested in firefox beta, but i'm sure it will work in your browser the same way.

Comment: C#/JS also pass native types like int by value.  However, that's not how Closures work. "a closure (also lexical closure or function closure) is a function or reference to a function together with a referencing environment—a table storing a reference to each of the non-local variables (also called free variables or upvalues) of that function.[1] A closure—unlike a plain function pointer—allows a function to access those non-local variables even when invoked outside its immediate lexical scope." - Wikipedia.  So nothing is being passed when using a closure to fold in values with limited scope.

Comment: If you want to use the same variable all through the for loop, you can do that too, without boxing. You just have to declare the variable outside the loop: `int i; for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) functionList.add((int x) => x + i);` will have all the functions add 10. This works with `for-in` too - it's only variables declared in the `for` statement itself that gets a new version per iteration.